# how to Post a JSON payload together with a multipartfile in the POSTMAN?

Tags: json, spring, rest, postman

in my Spring REST WS code:

I am using a Spring MultiPartFile

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFileAndSaveData(@RequestBody Person person, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
// do something to save the map to db
}
```

heres my JSON payloads :

```
{
   "firstname":"darell",
   "lastname":"abbott",
   "address":"philippines"
}
```

Postman payloads
[image: Payload]

Postman file
[image: File]

is there any way to put a JSON payloads and the `MultiPartFile` or a file to upload together in the postman or the POST method in a REST WebService doesn't allow a payload together with the `MultiPartFile`. please any help thnx.

Comment: please help me with this stuff. any solutions for this matter? thnx

Comment: add screenshot of `headers` tab? what headers did you set ?